# ATtiny85 MIDI IN using SoftwareSerial - Is it possible?

Tags: midi, attiny85

I'm trying to read MIDI notes using an ATtiny85 via SoftwareSerial; so far, I've got no success at all.

- The ATtiny is using the internal clock, 8Mhz, 5V.
- The MIDI keyboard sends clean note on/off messages (tested with a MIDI monitor).
- I've tried several test programs, particularly Nick Gammon's, as described [here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/14054/interfacing-an-attiny85-with-midi-via-software-serial?answertab=active#tab-top).
- I've followed Nick's schematics to build the connector, and I can confirm his program works with an Arduino, but not with the ATtiny.
- I calibrated the Tiny with OSCCAL - still no luck.
- As far as I can tell, `midiSerial.available()` is always 0, in every program I've tried.
- SoftwareSerial works fine for the purpose of MIDI out.

That's as far as I've got. I'd appreciate any pointers, especially if anyone else could try Nick's code and see if it works.

**EDIT**

There was an issue with my local version of SoftwareSerial. I had commented out code so that I could use pin change interrupts in my MIDI out program, but those interrupts are essential for MIDI input. Once I uncommented the code, all the programs I tested worked, so it is indeed possible to receive MIDI using an ATtiny.

That said, I've tried four keyboards as inputs and only one has worked so far, a Korg 01/W proX. The same happens when I load the MIDI code directly in the Arduino, so based on the answers below I will try a different optocoupler, and post my results here for the sake of improving on the answer.

Here's the schematics I was talking about:

[image: MIDI connections]

Comment: The schematic is wrong: pin 2 at the receiver must not be connected to ground, and the optocoupler is not reliable at MIDI speeds. See [4N35 opto-isolator for MIDI input does not work?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/314150)

Comment: You posted a link to a page that have a link to another page that contains the info your talking about.

Comment: true- I've just added the schematic above. The code is relevant because the author claims it's been tested, but it's one of several I've tried with identical results, so I don't think it is as central to the question.

Comment: Your link now points to a better schematic …

Comment: @LookAlterno there's no double jump - scroll down to "Example code for ATtiny85"

Comment: You might try [NeoSWSerial](https://github.com/SlashDevin/NeoSWSerial).  It has a configuration option to avoid the PCI vector problem, and it now supports the MIDI baud rate.  It is **MUCH** more efficient than `SoftwareSerial`.

Comment: I'd also say it's the opto isolator. I am getting good results with a 6N138. I also had good results with a 6N137 but based on reports from other people it seems that it can fail with certain devices.

Comment: @CL fixed up the earth pin on the schematic.

Answer (score 1):

I have done tests with a normal Arduino with software serial and missed quite a bit of messages, so I would advice to use hardware serial's instead.

For MIDI Out probably it works, but for MIDI In I have bad experiences. Especially when it comes to many messages, like aftertouch/pitch bend etc.

Also, I tried some optocouplers which didn't work well (like 6N137). I now use H11L1 optocouplers (they are white compared to most black ICs) and work perfectly.

You already checked the clean note on/note off ... are you sure it doesn't send active messages?

Below the schematic as I use it.. It does not matter if an STM32 or Arduino is used. Actually I haven't checked if H11L1 are 3.3V or 5V but they seem to work on both.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD7ayK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Yes, no other messages at all.

Comment: From yours and CLs comment it looks like I can't rely on the 435, so I'll try the H11L1.

Comment: It might be that different resistor values should be used, if you want I can check when I'm home this evening.

Comment: I'd be very grateful if you could :)

Comment: I added my circuit (hopefully without mistakes)

Comment: That looks great, I'll order the parts and report back asap!

Comment: Good luck .. btw I tried it earlier with an Arduino Uno/Mega (5V) and today with a STM32 (3.3V). ... both work. Btw, there is no difference between H11L1 and H11L1M except the manufacturer (some are white, some are black).

Comment: The pin numbers and several connections are wrong.

Comment: @CL I checked it and the only mistake I could find was the connection with the wire left of R2. I'm really interested what pin numbers/connections are wrong, because it is according to the circuit I built (on a breadboard).

Comment: DIN connector number the pins differently. R4 must be a pullup on the output signal. (And this schematic would be much more readable if you didn't try to connect all VCC and GND signals together; see, e.g., [this page](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/articles/MIDI).)

Comment: @CL Thank you for the comments ... true, I numbered the DIN pins myself (I will follow the original numbering, but get always confused about the side to look at). And a good tip about the VCC/GND ... I really used the pullup the way in the schematics and works, but I will check the official one and change mycircuit accordingly.